# how to show a custom activity on wearable while clicking a button on device activity?

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I want to show a custom activity on wearable since the notification on wearable is simple and I can't show couple of buttons in the first of notification on my watch (I don't want to slide left or right to find out how many option I have something like Pandora or google search on wearable I want)

My question is how can I show a custom layout/activity/view/etc... (rather complex than notification) on wearable while clicking on a button on my device?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

http://smartwatch.me/t/tutorial-how-to-develop-android-wear-apps-for-beginners-part-1-setup/684

you can follow this series this might help you a bit.

If you can get hold of this book it's even great.

http://www.learnandroidwear.com/